# VBA query to copy contents from excel file in sharepoint

Tags: excel, sharepoint, vba

I have some excel files in a share point folder. I would need the content from all the files to be collated to one single sheet using VBA.

I get the path as below and  try to connect to the path where the files are available.The below code is not able to connect or read the file from the path.

```
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As File

strspURL = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main").Cells(6, 7).Value

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(strspURL)
```

Comment: I recommend updating your question to say that, and showing us what you've tried thus far.

Comment: *The below code is not able to connect or read the file from the path* - [Map the Sharepoint Folder to a Network Drive](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2616712) and that will work. I have found this is the easiest solution when working with Sharepoint files.

Comment: Thanks, It worked